# ContextMenu in DataTemplate Binding issue

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

I have a context menu in LongListSelector.
This list is created and updated in runtime.

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SavedGamesHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-22,2" ItemsSource="{Binding SavedGames}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="12,2,0,20" Width="432">
                            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="RemoveSave_OnClick"/>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <Image Margin="10,5,10,0"  Height="173" Width="248" Source="{Binding Screen}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
                            <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock Tap="Save_OnTap" Tag="{Binding SavedGame}" Text="{Binding SaveName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GameName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Created on:" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Created}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Here's the method that handles click event on menu item

```
private void RemoveSave_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
        var saveViewModel = menuItem.DataContext as SavesViewModel;
        EmuStorageMgr.Instance.DeleteSave(saveViewModel.SavedGame.SaveFolder);
        App.ViewModel.RescanSaves();
    }
```

The following method populates the SavedGames list

```
public ObservableCollection<SavesViewModel> SavedGames { get; private set; }
public void RescanSaves()
    {
        SavedGames.Clear();
        var saves = EmuStorageMgr.Instance.GetSaves();
        foreach (var save in saves)
        {
            SavedGames.Add(new SavesViewModel(save));
        }
        this.IsSavesLoaded = true;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SavedGames");
    }
```

So, when the SavedGames collection is populaed for the first time it work perfect, but when the collections changes (delete some old items, add new) I observe some strange behaviour. When the OnClick event is fired I see menuItem.DataContext is not for the menu item I clicked but for some old menu items which were deleted.

Comment: When your collection changes, do your menu items as well? I think it may have something to do with how the binding is done and one side is not updating.

Comment: for example, RemoveSave_OnClick can remove the item, each time it calls  RescanSaves which clears the collection and re-populates it again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't leave a comment on you're post so I'll say here:

This is a known problem and one that I have also. I haven't found any way to fully resolve this issue and haven't seen any recent solutions. You can see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084779/contextmenus-menuitem-datacontext-returns-old-items)to ensure the issue is in line with yours.

**The only solution I've seen so far is described here in a [msdn blog from '11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/05/11/we-ve-secretly-changed-this-control-s-datacontext-let-s-see-if-it-notices-workaround-for-a-silverlight-data-binding-bug-affecting-various-scenarios-including-datagrid-contextmenu.aspx). It identifies the problem in the Silverlight Framework and he provides a workaround which I implemented. Include the class file in your project and make use of the XAML tags, and it will allow your contextmenu keep in sync with the parent's datacontext. I've ran into a small side-effect using it, so it's only a band aid.**

I also found tell from another forum that it's a known issue with no solution, but a patch may be found at [codeplex here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/patches). My issue with the patch is I couldn't figure out how to implement it, and also the LLS (which is what I'm using the ContextMenu with) has migrated directly into the SDK, so I was stuck.

That's all I've dug up on the problem, hope it helps. If someone else has anymore to add please do.

**Update:**
Using some of what was in the above provided links, I think I have a slightly better solution. In the ContextMenu Unloaded event, refresh the view. Something like:

```
    private void add_but_up(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu conmen = (sender as ContextMenu);
        conmen.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty);
    }
```

This is essentially what the patch in the blog does. Only in a completely different context. So my issues were an inability to use functions like ScrollTo(). Doing this in the code behind of the actual page seems fix the ContextMenu binding issue.